# meaning and authenticity of Japanese proverb about shrimp and jellyfish

Tags: proverbs

On [this page](https://kamengshambhala.wordpress.com/2017/04/29/japanese-wisdom-quotes/), I see the following listed as a Japanese proverb:

```
クラゲはエビと踊ることは決してありません 。
The jellyfish never dances with the shrimp.
Meaning: Enmity is inborn and natural, it can never be eliminated.
```

However, doing searches in Japanese for this doesn't yield anything online.

My theory is that this is either:

1) A very old proverb which is uncommon.

2) Actually from another language which somehow got back-translated into Japanese.

3) 'Evolved' from what it was originally.

Can anyone speak to the authenticity of this proverb? If it is authentic, can you confirm the meaning as well?

Comment: Don't jellyfish eat shrimp?

Comment: It sounds funny though, it’s gibberish to me. A bit Murakami-esque phrase(metaphor) to me rather than a proverb. I simply imagine a jellyfish is contending with a shrimp.

Comment: It’s not a proverb nor a saying. Never heard that expression. I doubt the authenticity of even ‘this page’. I won’t recommend you to learn Japanese with the website.

Comment: Want to comment again what I commented here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/question-about-supposedly-a-japanese-proverb

Comment: Thanks everyone, looks like this likely came from another language, or was (recently) invented by someone...Feel free to leave a proper answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen such a saying. Perhaps 犬猿の仲 or 水と油 would be similar in meaning.

Some "proverbs" in the link are real ones, but many are not only unheard but also nonsensical. To list a few, I'm pretty certain that these are machine-translated gibberish.

> - 決して山を登ることはできません。富士、あなたは馬鹿だし、二度以上登ると、あなたは馬鹿だ。 (although there is a [similar saying](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E7%99%BB%E3%82%89%E3%81%AC%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E3%80%81%E4%BA%8C%E5%BA%A6%E7%99%BB%E3%82%8B%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF))
> - 知恵のない知識は愚か者の本の負荷です。
> - 風が巨大なオークに落ちるかもしれませんが、竹は地面にも曲がって、嵐の通過後直立しま。
> - 100マイル走る者は、90点を半分と考えるべきです。

Apparently the author doesn't even know mile is not used in Japan :)

Comment: Thanks Naruto, good points I should have read the rest of that page more carefully (: